# Quasar + TypeScript + Class-based Components: Property '$route' does not exist on type 'Page'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router, quasar-framework

I know this should be a pretty obvious issue, but I think I'm experiencing something more complex than what most answers would suggest. To start, my issue:

[image]

The raw code if you wish to copy/paste is:

```
<template>
    <q-page class="row items-center justify-evenly">
        <p>Aggregate data page</p>
    </q-page>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class AggPage extends Vue {
    mounted() {
        if (this.$route) console.log(this.$route.query);
    }
}
</script>
```

This is coming from a Quasar project that I recently spun up. I've made no adjustments to the `quasar.conf.js`, I've installed no plugins, and I've installed no additional NodeJS dependencies beyond what Quasar provides.

I did some prior research on the issue and tried to solve it by updating `shim-vue.d.ts` with the following:

```
// Recommended fix
declare module "vue/types/vue" {
    import VueRouter, { Route } from "vue-router";
    interface Vue {
        $router: VueRouter;
        $route: Route;
    }
}
// Me getting desperate
declare module "vue-property-decorator" {
    import VueRouter, { Route } from "vue-router";
    interface Vue {
        $router: VueRouter;
        $route: Route;
    }
}
```

I've also tried re-installing my `node_modules` and restarting VSCode. I tried putting the module declaration in the `routes.ts`, as well.

What **did** work was putting the module declaration inline in my Vue template like so:

```
<template>
    <q-page class="row items-center justify-evenly">
        <p>Aggregate data page</p>
    </q-page>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";
import VueRouter, { Route } from "vue-router";

declare module "vue-property-decorator" {
    interface Vue {
        $router: VueRouter;
        $route: Route;
    }
}

@Component
export default class AggPage extends Vue {
    mounted() {
        if (this.$route) console.log(this.$route.query);
    }
}
</script>
```

[image]

Obviously I don't want to re-declare this module ***every time I read a route on any page***, so I'm looking for a better solution. I don't understand why the global definition file (`shim-vue.d.ts`) didn't work...

### Update

Something else that works weirdly but I don't fully understand why yet:

```
<template>
    <q-page class="row items-center justify-evenly">
        <p>Aggregate data page</p>
    </q-page>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";
import "vue-router"; // <---- the only new line

@Component
export default class AggPage extends Vue {
    mounted() {
        if (this.$route) console.log(this.$route.query);
    }
}
</script>
```

By importing `vue-router` (despite not using any of the imports) it started working.